# How to add REST API to console app written in .NET Framework 4.8 using .NET generic host?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written a small Windows service that hosts a number of IHostedService based classes using the .NET generic host. I'd like to add the ability to talk to the service through a REST API, and thought the .NET generic host setup should let me do that fairly easily: just add Microsoft.AspNetCore, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting and start with adding a .ConfigureWebHost to the IHostBuilder. But it seems like the combination of .NET Framework and .NET generic host prohibits that from working.... The program.cs looks roughly like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Myservice
{
  class Program
  {
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
      IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(...)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(...)
        // ConfigureWebHost can't be found by the compiler
        // Neither can .ConfigureWebHostDefaults
        .ConfigureWebHost(...)
        .ConfigureLogging(...)
        .ConfigureServices(...);

      if (CommandLine.RunAsService)
      {
        builder.UseWindowsService();
      }

      await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

I've seen some hints that the particular project type matters. I started out with a standard .NET Framework Console App - so project file looking something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
...
```

but have also tried with a project built from the ASP.NET Core Web Application template using .NET Framework. (.NET Framework is a requirement to make use of particular assemblies the service needs.) That looked something like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

It seems like this ought to work somehow, but I can't find the right combination....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, it looks like the .NET Generic Host was brought to .NET Framework, but that the portion of it which held the web host was in AspNetCore, specifically in version 3, and that has yet to be supported in .NET Framework. So although it'd be nice if this worked, it likely isn't going to until .NET 5.

Comment: Does it work under 5? It looks like the extension methods are in the NuGet package, but `ConfigureWebHost` is only applicable to ASP.NET Core according to the MSDN page. I'm assuming this does not and will not work (Core web host inside a Framework app).

Comment: To be honest, I haven't checked. I wanted to use the REST API as a sort of semi-open IPC, but ended up moving away from REST and toward gRPC instead. The nice thing about gRPC is, although it *can* be hosted in a web service, it doesn't need to be. I used grpcdotnetnamedpipes to allow connection over named pipes, and everything seems to be working smoothly with that instead.